# I need help on Optimization of Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, chart.js, laravel-6

I'm creating different charts based on the data I have in the database. I've succeeded to create the charts but there are so many queries executed. From the controller, I want to create chart of individuals by gender and individuals by age group.

My Controller File

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Individual;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class IndividualDashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $gender = $this->get_gender();
        $count_gender = $this->count_gender();
        $age_group = $this->get_age_group();
        $count_age_group = $this->count_age_group();
        return view('individuals.dashboard',compact('gender','count_gender','age_group','count_age_group'));
    }

    //Get User Gender name
    function get_gender ()
    {
        $gender = Individual::select('gender')->groupBy('gender')->orderBy('gender','desc')->pluck('gender');
        return $gender;
    }

    //Count user  by gender
    function count_gender()
    {
        $gender = $this->get_gender();
        if(!empty($gender)){
            foreach ($gender as $sex) {
                $count[] = Individual::where('gender',$sex)->count();
            }
        }
        return json_encode($count);
    }

    //Get Individuals Age Groups
    function get_age_group ()
    {
        $gender = Individual::select('age_group')->groupBy('age_group')->orderBy('age_group','desc')->pluck('age_group');
        return $gender;
    }

    //Count Individual by gender
    function count_age_group()
    {
        $age_groups = $this->get_age_group()->toArray();
        if(!empty($age_groups)){
            foreach ($age_groups as $age_group) {
                $count[] = Individual::where('age_group',$age_group)->count();
            }
        }
        return json_encode($count);
    }

}
```

My View File

```
<script>
        //Show graph of individuals count by gender
        var ctx = document.getElementById('genderCount');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: {!! $gender !!},
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# Individual By Gender',
                    data: {!! $count_gender !!},
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'pink',
                        'blue',
                        'gray',
                    ],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        }
                    }]
                },

            }
        });

        //Show graph of individuals count by age group
        var ageGroup = document.getElementById('ageGroup');
        var myChart = new Chart(ageGroup, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: {!! $age_group !!},
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# Individual By Age',
                    data: {!! $count_age_group !!},
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'red',
                        'green',
                        'orange',
                        'purple',
                        'olive',
                        'maroon'
                    ],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This works but on the debugger toolbar it shows 14 queries executed as shown on the image below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there aren't much to improve since you need to get data per gender and per age group. I have made a few changes to the code but nothing special.

````php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Individual;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class IndividualDashboardController extends Controller
{
    //Get User Gender name
    private function get_gender ()
    {
        return Individual::select('gender')->get();
    }

    //Count user  by gender
    private function count_gender()
    {
        $gender = $this->get_gender();
        if(!empty($gender)){
            foreach ($gender as $sex) {
                $count[] = Individual::where('gender', $sex)->count();
            }
        }
        return json_encode($count);
    }

    //Get Individuals Age Groups
    private function get_age_group ()
    {
        return Individual::select('age_group')->get();
    }

    //Count Individual by gender
    private function count_age_group()
    {
        $age_groups = $this->get_age_group()->toArray();
        if(!empty($age_groups)){
            foreach ($age_groups as $age_group) {
                $count[] = Individual::where('age_group', $age_group)->count();
            }
        }
        return json_encode($count);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
       return view('individuals.dashboard', [
           'gender' => $this->get_gender(),
           'count_gender' => $this->count_gender(),
           'age_group' => $this->get_age_group(),
           'count_age_group' => $this->count_age_group(),
       ]);
    }

}
```
````